# API Platform & Symfony: what is the correct way to make a custom controller for collection operations?

Tags: api, symfony, api-platform.com

As far as I understand, Api Platform deletes and updates one by one the resources of a Collection. For example, I have an Activity Entity, which has a Many-To-One relation with OpeningHours: if I want to delete or add multiples OpeningHours through an Admin Back Office, I must call a "delete" operation for each openingHour with its unique @id. As long as I have very few OpeningHours, it's quite all right : the job is done in a few seconds. But what am I supposed to do when I have thousand of them ? Just wait ?
So I've created a Custom Controller and a Custom Route - so far only for the Delete Operation ; the update operation will come after.

First Question : is this the right way to do it or have I missed something in the docs?

Here is my API configuration for the Activity Entity:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *      collectionOperations={
 *         "get"={"normalization_context"={"groups"="activity:list"}},
 *         "post"={"denormalization_context"={"groups"="activity:post"}},
 *      },
 *      itemOperations={
 *          "get"={"normalization_context"={"groups"="activity:item"}},
 *          "put"={"denormalization_context"={"groups"="activity:item"}},
            "delete_opening_hours"={
 *             "method"="DELETE",
 *             "path"="/admin/activity/{id}/delete_opening_hours",
 *             "controller"=DeleteOpeningHoursAction::class,             
 *             "read"=false,
 *         },
*          "delete", "patch"
 *     },  
 *     attributes={"pagination_items_per_page"=10}
 * )
```

And my Custom Controller :

```
/**
 * Class DeleteOpeningHoursAction
 * @Security("is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')")
 */
final class DeleteOpeningHoursAction extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route(
     *     name="delete_opening_hours",
     *     path="/admin/activity/{id}/delete_opening_hours",
     *     methods={"DELETE"},     
     * )
     */
    public function deleteHours(Activity $data):Activity
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
        $activity = $em->getRepository('App\Entity\Activity')->find($data);
        $openingHours = $activity->getOpeningHours();

        foreach ($openingHours as $hour) {
            $em->remove($hour);
        }
   
        $em->flush();  
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setStatusCode(204);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

It does the requested job: all the OpeningHours are deleted at once, but it returns a 500 Error:

```
Return value of App\Controller\Action\DeleteOpeningHoursAction::deleteHours() must be an instance of App\Entity\Activity, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response returned
```

And if I return $activity instead of the response above, the error message becomes :

```
Return value of App\Controller\Action\DeleteOpeningHoursAction::deleteHours() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, instance of App\Entity\Activity returned
```

So what am I doing wrong? What is the correct response for a Custom Controller?
I'm quite confused.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please check for your return types: why did you set the return type to `Activity`, but return a usual response?

Comment: I'm sorry, I over-simplified the second test. The correct current code is : `[...] $em->flush(); return $activity;` and the full answer in this case is `The controller must return a "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response" object but it returned an object of type App\Entity\Activity.` It is unhappy whatever my response, even "null".

Comment: Oh God, I read your comment again, I read my code again. And again. And I saw. What a waste of (everybody's) time. Fixed it. I was so focused on the last lines I missed the obvious.